# Different coordinate extent of reclassfied slope in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, extents

I have a slope file generated from a reprojected file. Both files have the same coordinate extent. From the slope file, I reclassified the slope using the Raster Analysis: Reclassify by table.  However, the resulting reclassified slope map has a different coordinate extent. What went wrong?

Comment: Can you share the log ?